# How to install openvpn cli from an electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, openvpn

I am making an electron app that connects to openvpn using its config `.ovpn` file. Is there a way to install the openvpn cli on the users system in the background without prompting the user, when the app is run for the first time irrespective of the OS? (I'm targeting Mac, Linux and Windows)

I've tried to do this with `sudo-prompt` and `electron-sudo`and while the app works, it's a lot of hassle for the user to be prompted multiple times for their password.

Comment: The only alternative is to run your whole app as root (on Linux) such that your users will be prompted upon application startup once. However, this is generally not advisable unless there's no other option. Installing something should only be a one-time action, however, so I'm unsure what you mean by being "pormpted multiple times". Once OpenVPN is installed, you should be able to just connect using the `.ovpn`.

Comment: I can connect using the `,ovpn` file, but it requires sudo access on linux and mac and admin access on windows.